# Unable to pull record from array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am trying to remove an item from an array of objects by using Mongoose 'pull'. I am getting a status code of 200 and apparently everything is fine but the record is not actually removed? The userId in mongo db looks like:

> userId: ObjectId("6b275260a6g58308e510721b")

```
exports.putDislike = (req, res, next) => {
  const productId = req.body.productId;
  const userId = req.body.userId;

  Product.findById(productId)
  .then(product => {
    if (!product) {
      return next(new Error('Product not found.'));
    }
     product.requests.pull(userId)
     return product.save()
     .then(result => {
        res.status(200).json({ message: "Item request removed." });
     })
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Removing request failed." });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you are using pull correctly, check out this link https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/

According to that, i think your code should be somehing like the example below:

```
exports.putDislike = (req, res, next) => {
  const productId = req.body.productId;
  const userId = req.body.userId;

  Product.update(
    { "_id": productId },
    { $pull: { requests: {userId: userId} } })
  .then(result => {
      res.status(200).json({ message: "Item request removed." });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).json({ message: "Removing request failed." });
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for that, will try it out. I saw this in the docs `doc.subdocs.pull(4815162342);` https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.updateOne

Comment: Had to change your code a bit but got it to work. This: `{ $pull: { requests: userId } })` needs to be `{ $pull: { requests: {userId: userId} } }`